# SharePoint Hybrid 2013 + SPO365 CSOM REST

Tags: csom, sharepoint-hosted-app, hybrid-solution

once the environment is set up, is it possible to create a Cross-Domain JSOM or REST calls to get data from Site Collections from Both On-Prem and Online Sides using the SharePoint Hosted App Add-in model ?

Comment: Why JSOM and not CSOM in C#? Do you need to make app-only calls to the site collections?

Comment: we are moving away from C# CSOM as we are planning to move fully to Online and we don't want to depend on Provider hosted add-ins